# Running two separate SQL queries on one php page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've manage to find lots of answers for merging SQL queries of multiple tables but I'm a newbie and want to run two completely separate queries on two different tables and display the results on a single .php page.

Unfortunately I receive a "**Notice: Undefined index:**" error. So I guess, my question is, how do I define an index on the first or second query to avoid the error?

Query 1 displays info from a table containing sightings data, the second query is to display a list of news items on the same .php page.

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm very new to PHP and SQL... but you can already tell that!

Huge thanks for any help, it will be very much appreciated!!

Cheers

Steve

---

Heres' my SQL:

```
<?php require_once('inc/connection.php');?>

    <?php
    // connect to MySQL
    $conn = dbConnect('read', 'pdo');
    // prepare the SQL query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wbcsightings WHERE spYear = year(curdate()) AND spFirstDate IS NOT NULL";
    $wbcsightings = $conn->query($sql);
    $error = $conn->errorInfo();
    if (isset($error[2])) die($error[2]);
    $numRows = $wbcsightings->fetchColumn();
    $wbcsightings->closeCursor();
    ?>

    <?php
    // connect to MySQL
    $conn = dbConnect('read', 'pdo');
    // prepare the SQL query
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM wbcnews WHERE newsDisplay="yes" ORDER BY newsDate desc';
    $wbcnews = $conn->query($sql);
    $error = $conn->errorInfo();
    if (isset($error[2])) die($error[2]);
    $numRows = $wbcnews->fetchColumn();
    $wbcnews->closeCursor();
    ?>
```

And here's the code I'm using to display the results of the first query (table wbcsightings)

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) { if($i==3) break;?>
<?php echo $row['spName']; ?>
<?php echo $row['spFirstDate']; ?>
<?php echo $row['spLocation']; ?>
<?php echo $row['spRecorder']; ?>
<?php $i++;} ?>
```

And the code to display the results of the second query (table wbcnews)

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) { if($i==3) break;?>
<?php echo $row['newsTitle']; ?>
<?php echo $row['newsDate']; ?>
<?php echo $row['newsSubTitle']; ?>
<?php echo $row['newsAuthor']; ?>
<?php $i++;} ?>
```

Comment: first one hint: you don't need (and shouldn't do) a `<?php .... ?> for each line

Comment: what line is the error point to? the first block of output needs to be after the first block of code, as you are resuing variables

Comment: if this is the order your code _is_ in your php file, then the problem is, that you use 1 variable name for 2 different things and expect php to know what variable you mean right now. This applies to `$sql` here. You also should _not_ query the same query twice if not needed.

Comment: You're overwriting $numRows. When trying to display the first entry, $numRows already contains the second entry. edit: not entirely correct.. but you overwrite $sql as well, and then rund the same query for both views

Comment: Wow... thank you to @Jeff, rtfm and Lars-Stegelitz for replying so quickly. You people are amazing!!

So, I fixed the second query replacing $sql with $news and modified the code to display the results and it works!!! 

Thank you everyone... I'm having a late night on this.. now I will be able to sleep happy tonight!

Cheers all... really appreciate your fast response. Brilliant!! :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your solution is simple, just change either one of your $sql to another name of variable (ex: $sql1), so you can fetch both of your query with **$sql** and **$sql1**, the **undefined index** happen because you store new query to the same variable, which replace the first query, so with 2 queries with different name it will not cause the **undefined index**, also, you don't have to separate the query, you can use

```
$conn = dbConnect('read', 'pdo');
// prepare the SQL query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wbcsightings ........
....
$sql1 = "'SELECT * FROM wbcnews.......
....
```

and for fetch you can use

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) { if($i==3) break;?>
......
<?php $i=0; foreach ($conn->query($sql1) as $row) { if($i==3) break;?>
......
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Reuse your existing connection:

```
<?php require_once('inc/connection.php');?>

<?php
// connect to MySQL
$conn = dbConnect('read', 'pdo');
// prepare the SQL query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wbcsightings WHERE spYear = year(curdate()) AND spFirstDate IS NOT NULL";
$wbcsightings = $conn->query($sql);
$error = $conn->errorInfo();
if (isset($error[2])) die($error[2]);
$numRows = $wbcsightings->fetchColumn(); // note: ->rowCount(); for actual row count. your syntax is pulling first column data only
$wbcsightings->closeCursor();
?>

<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM wbcnews WHERE newsDisplay="yes" ORDER BY newsDate desc';
// REUSE EXISTING connection
$wbcnews = $conn->query($sql);
$error = $conn->errorInfo();
if (isset($error[2])) die($error[2]);
//ASSIGN another variable for wbcnews row count
$numRows2 = $wbcnews->fetchColumn(); // note: ->rowCount(); for actual row count. your syntax is pulling first column data only
$wbcnews->closeCursor();
?>
```

You already have the results in $wbcsightings so foreach it directly (don't requery):

```
<?php 
 $i=0; foreach ($wbcsightings as $row) { if($i==3) break;
 echo $row['spName'];
 echo $row['spFirstDate'];
 echo $row['spLocation'];
 echo $row['spRecorder'];
 $i++;} 
?>
```

Same for $wbcnews (don't requery):

```
<?php 
 $i=0; foreach ($wbcnews as $row) { if($i==3) break;
 echo $row['newsTitle']; 
 echo $row['newsDate']; 
 echo $row['newsSubTitle']; 
 echo $row['newsAuthor']; 
 $i++;}
?>
```

Lastly, the **undefined index** error was due to your **last** used $sql (wbcnews) running through the first foreach loop, since wbcnews doesn't have indexes 'spName', 'spFirstDate', 'spLocation', or 'spRecorder', the error was fatal.